# How to improve this webscraping python script?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

Brief context, I started Python two weeks ago so don't hesitate to correct any mistake or improvement you see.I am trying to scrape data from the results club list of the site www.fff.fr .

My way of organizing it is:

1. Go to Homepage
2. Accept Cookies
3. Use search bar for cityname
4. Get result list
5. Follow each url of the result page
6. Go to each "Staff" sub-section
7. Extract data from this page

I started to build the below python code which is not working so far. I'd be really interested in feedback on how to actually make it work.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from shutil import which

chrome_path = which("chromedriver")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get("https://fff.fr")

cookie_btn = driver.find_element_by_id("didomi-notice-agree-button")
cookie_btn.click()

search_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html//form[@id='proximiteSearch']//input[@id='fff_club_form_club_near_to_search_address']")
search_input.send_keys("Paris")
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

self.html = driver.page_source
driver.close()

def parse(self, response):
        resp = Selector(text=self.html)
        clubs = resp.xpath("(//ul[contains(@id, 'listresulclub')])/li/text()")
        for club in clubs:
            name = club.xpath(".//text()").get()
            name_link = club.xpath(".//@href").get()

            url = f"https://www.ffr.fr{name_link}"
            absolute_url = url[:-10] + "/le-staff"
            # absolute_url =  response.urljoin()

            yield scrapy.Request(url=absolute_url, meta={'club_name':name})
            #yield response.follow (url = name_link, callback=self.parse_country, meta={'club_name': name})

def parse_country(self, response):
        name = response.request.meta['club_name']
        contacts = response.xpath("//div[@class='coor-block-content']/ol")
        for contact in contacts:
            contact_nom = contact.xpath(".//li[1]/text()").get()
            yield {
                'club_name': name,
                'correspondant_nom': contact_nom
            }
```

Comment: Please specify what isn't working exactly. Which of the steps above do work?

Comment: I will just give you some tips. In my opinion, selenium is the way to go. When automating something or trying to extract data, you have to think what would you do if you did it manually. Try splitting the tasks in main functions so you can test them one by one to check if you get what you want. This way is easier to find your errors and to update them later. Keep trying!

Comment: Also, both functions are never called/used in the code you provided so that part of your code is not executed. Maybe try doing `parse(self.html)` underneath `driver.close()`?

Answer (score 0):

**You can try the same thing without selenium and it works:**

```
import bs4
import requests
import sys
import re 
import unicodedata
import os
import random
import datetime

Current_Date_Formatted = datetime.datetime.today().strftime ('%d-%b-%Y')
time = str(Current_Date_Formatted)

filename = "footballstuff"
cityname = sys.argv[1]

filename=r"D:\Huzefa\Desktop\\" +filename+ ".txt"
url = "https://www.fff.fr/resultats?search="+cityname
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")


file = open(filename , 'wb')
for i in soup.select("a"):
    f=i.text
    file.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", f)).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    file.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", os.linesep)).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    file.write(unicodedata.normalize('NFD', re.sub("[\(\[].*?[\)\]]", "", os.linesep)).encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
file.close()
```